# CAS Rest Protocol Does not work without Generic Service Definition

Tags: java, cas, apiomat

I want to use REST Protocol in my services. For this, I enabled Rest Protocol and trying to get TGT. Also, all examples were based on generic service registration which I don't want in prod environment.

[Here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/services/JSON-Service-Management.html#json-syntax) is the generic service registry example that should **not** be used in prod environment. And I did not use this in my environment:

```
{
  /*
    Generic service definition that applies to https/imaps urls
    that wish to register with CAS for authentication.
  */
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^(https|imaps)://.*",
  "name" : "HTTPS and IMAPS",
  "id" : 10000001,
}
```

Instead, I have the following one:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  // this service will match all the requests contains test in the request url
  "serviceId": "^https?:\\/\\/.*test($|\\/).*$",
  "name": "Test",
  "id": 1,
  "description": "Test service",
  "evaluationOrder": 2,
  "requiredHandlers": [
    "java.util.HashSet",
    [
      "TestHandler"
    ]
  ],
  "attributeReleasePolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy"
  },
  "properties": {
    "@class": "java.util.HashMap",
    "jwtAsServiceTicket": {
      "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values": [
        "java.util.HashSet",
        [
          "true"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can not request a ticket granting ticket as [explained here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html#request-a-ticket-granting-ticket):

```
POST /cas/v1/tickets HTTP/1.0
'Content-type': 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
username=battags&password=password&additionalParam1=paramvalue
```

I got the following exception:

```
Unauthorized Service Access. Service [] is not found in service registry
```

When I debug the code, I can see that TGT is created and my registered service works fine. An exception is thrown because of the registered service check for againts CAS Server in [JWTBuilder](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/support/cas-server-support-token-core-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/token/JwtBuilder.java#L134):

```
    val registeredService = payload.getRegisteredService() == null
        ? locateRegisteredService(serviceAudience)
        : payload.getRegisteredService();
    RegisteredServiceAccessStrategyUtils.ensureServiceAccessIsAllowed(registeredService);
```

Here CAS tries to check if service access is allowed. payload.getRegisteredService returns null and locateRegisteredService is called with serviceAudience, than ensureServiceAccessIsAllowed throws the exception.

Problem is: **serviceAudience** is [always filled](https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/master/support/cas-server-support-token-core-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/token/JwtTokenTicketBuilder.java#L78) with **CAS server prefix** which means this there must a service definition that matches with **CAS server prefix**. All examples work when I enable generic service definition but when I remove it, TGT does not return because of the above check.

Any idea, solution? I don't want to allow everyone able to create TGT, I can add service definition that only matches with CAS prefix also but first it is better to understand if I miss something or if this is a bug.

My Cas version: 6.1.0

My configurations:

```
server.port=8095
server.servlet.context-path=/bouncer
cas.authn.policy.any.tryAll=false
cas.authn.policy.any.enabled=true
cas.serviceRegistry.initFromJson=true
cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file:/services
```

My build:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <manifestFile>${manifestFileToUse}</manifestFile>
                </archive>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-jcl-2.12.1.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-jul-2.12.1.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j18-impl-2.12.1.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/log4j-web-2.12.1.jar</exclude>
                            <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}.jar</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
            <!--START: Extend CAS as WebApp-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: Logback Gelf(Graylog Extended Log Format) integration-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.siegmar</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
                <version>${logback-gelf.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: Java 11 integration problems, use older logback and slf4j until it is supported-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback-classic.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!-- TODO: Problem The following two deps are needed for sending traces to zipkin -->
            <!-- Problem: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1193 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-sleuth</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!--this one is needed, because else an exception will be thrown caused
               by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/servo/monitor/Monitors-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
                <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
                <version>${servo-core.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- START: Support JWT/CAS Protocol: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-token-tickets</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!-- START: REST Endpoints enabled for cli authentications -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-rest-tokens</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>

                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!-- START: JSON Service Registry Enabled -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-json-service-registry</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: OIDC Protocol enabled-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-oidc</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: Enable consul client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-consul-client</artifactId>
                <version>${cas-server-support-consul-client.version}</version>

                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: Enable Custom Authentication for CAS: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/Configuring-Custom-Authentication.html-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-core-authentication-api</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-core-api-configuration-model</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-core-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

            <!--START: Enable Logback Support: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/logging/Logging-Logback.html#logback-logging-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                <artifactId>cas-server-support-logback</artifactId>
                <version>${cas.version}</version>

                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>

                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <!-- NotNull annotation comes from this package conflicts with hibarnate for ConsulProperties class-->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>edu.washington.cs.types.checker</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checker-framework</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!--END-->

        </dependencies>
```

Comment: What does your build file look like? Also, what is the CAS version? Please be specific.

Comment: My version is 6.1.0 and I added my configurations to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea, solution? I don't want to allow everyone able to create TGT, I can add service definition that only matches with CAS prefix also but first it is better to understand if I miss something or if this is a bug.

You're not missing anything. This sounds like a bug to me. As a workaround, I would add the service definition that matches the CAS prefix for now.

It sounds like this problem likely only manifests itself because you're using this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-token-tickets</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you have no need for this, then you can remove it to also remove the problem. Otherwise for now, your workaround for *add service definition that only matches with CAS prefix* should do.

PS You can try to switch to `6.1.2` but I dont think that would at make a difference in this case; it's a good idea to switch anyway.